# How do I pass & receive value from tabscreen to other screen?

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, jsx

I'm trying to pass values like this:

```
     <Tab.Screen
    name="InProgress"
    children={()=><InProgress propName={"propValue"}/>}
    options={{
      tabBarLabel: 'In Progress',
      tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
        <Icon name="download" size={25}/>
      )
    
    }}/>
```

How do I receive the value from other screens? Or is there any other way?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DC7f.png)

Comment: Can you please paste here the code as text instead of image? Thank you! Also it's just a guess but you are trying to pass a function definition, try instead the component only like `children={<InProgress propName={"propValue"}/>}`.

Comment: I have passed the values like this and it worked. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is you are passing a function definition to `children` attribute. Instead as I mentioned in the comment section, you can pass the value to `children` attribute as:

```
<Tab.Screen name="InProgress"
            children={ <InProgress propName={"propValue"} /> }
            options={{
              tabBarLabel: 'In Progress',
              tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
                <Icon name="download" size={25}/>
            )}}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use props to pass data from parent to child component.. I hope that it works